# System based on users-roles from scratch or use framework?

Tags: php, session, zend-framework, authentication, zend-framework2

I need develop basic login and session manager base on users-roles-privileges pattern for my app.

For example:

- Guest  view
- Editor  view/add/edit
- admin   view/add/edit/delete

and create session during the user is active.

I was searching in the web and I found that [ACL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list) and [RBAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control) are the most accepted implementations, there are devs the prefer develop their own implementation and other that defend use some framework, like zend.

Is not about fans or pros and cons, about reinvent or not the wheel, I want more clarify by developer that have experience with both (preferably).

Is more about security vs learning curve... If is more secure use those components (or others) or write from scratch using standard rules for authentication and permissions?

Should I develop from scratch or use existing project like 
[zend_acl](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.permissions.acl.intro.html) and [zend_auth](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.authentication.intro.html)?

Comment: " I want know opinion of developer that have experience with both" it's clearly primary opinion based, stackoverflow isn't intended for this.

Comment: Sorry, I should not user the word opinion, I should explain me better... Is about security vs learning curve... If is more secure use those components or others or write from scratch using standard rules for authentication and permissions?

Comment: Edit your question then, or delete it and rephrase it in another question

Comment: I edited the question for clarify...

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't re-invent the wheel unless you're confident in your knowledge of the subject matter. If you're not an ACL or RBAC expert, let someone else do the heavy lifting.

https://github.com/ZF-Commons/zfc-rbac is a perfectly acceptable, basic RBAC implementation for ZF2, ready to go. It'll get you a long way before you need a custom implementation.

Comment: Your argue is very simple, but some acceptable. There are lot of documentation about ACL and RBAC. In simple words what are the advantages of both.